# Where to store my data?

Tags: vb.net

Am developing software in VB.NET that needs to store related information of Contacts etc. I can't use MS-SQL or MySQL as Database because if I do that, then if I've to install on another PC, I'll also need to install MS-SQL on that PC. Isn't there any "built-in Database" in VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataSets. Have a look [here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dotnetperls.com%2Fdataset-vbnet&ei=coVOUeGBCsak0QXZ-YHgCQ&usg=AFQjCNFzW3WHfeYnQ491W6QaEZZucMCb8g&sig2=3RrZtYUyEqGe0O8sDQbXuQ&bvm=bv.44158598,d.d2k&cad=rja).

Answer (score 0):

Based off your use case about needing to store relational data but not being able to install a full-fledged database server product, it sounds like your application benefit from using an embedded database.

There was a previous question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684595/embedded-database-for-net)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **XML** with `Datasets`. You need not to install any software, and there are tons of guides on how to read/write from/to XML files.

Another solution would be `SQL Compact`; it's kinda like SQLite (doesn't require installation)

**SQL Compact**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx

**XML Solutions Samples:**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13854/Using-XML-as-Database-with-Dataset
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/343670/use-of-xml-file-in-c-instead-of-database

Answer (score 0):

If your are dealing with a significant amount of data, a database is the appropriate solution. SQL Express is free, works well with VB and is, well, moderately easy to package as a pre-requisite with your msi file when you build the installer.