# Embedded database for stand alone desktop application C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, desktop-application

Is there a database engine which fulfills the following requirements?

My desktop application (with C# .net) requirements are:

1. it must be embedded with the application
2. it must have full text search feature on blob data
3. database limit must have maximum capacity (up to 10 gb)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684595/embedded-database-for-net 
Sql server compact doesn't support FTS but you can use Lucene.net or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite has [140 terabytes](http://sqlite.org/limits.html) maximum database size, and [full text search](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1)