# Using C# to read Database files WITHOUT having a database program installed?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm quite new to databases, although I've been doing tutorials and such to come up to speed, and I got to wondering: If I have a database that was created in MySQL or MSSQL, can I access it using C# without having a database server installed on the machine?
And if I write a program that uses a small database, say 4 tables with less than 100 elements each, how would I go about deploying that in my released C# program?  Please bare in mind that this question isn't about the merits of using a database in a program, it's about the mechanics of accessing a database file (.mdf), from a released C# program, without having a database server installed on the target machine.  I've seen various articles on the MSDN dealing with this, but I haven't found one that answers this question.

Thanks

Comment: It is actually pretty *uncommon* to have a database program installed on the client...

Comment: well, you must have drivers to access the database.. And it would be usefull for testing to access the dabase on the "test"server

Comment: If I understand what Marc said, I can embed the database in the application, and use the C# libraries to access the mdf file.  I'm not sure if that means embedding a database server or just using the C# libraries to access the mdf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are essentially 3 types of database implementations:

- server install - think "SQL Server", "Oracle" - here, the database is purely on the server; the caller requires the *client library* (i.e. something that understands the database protocol), but that can usually be deployed as part of the application, or is part of a standard framework that is already on the machine; here the central server would typically service multiple clients concurrently
- client install - think "SQL Server Express" etc - here there is a dedicated database utility installed on the **client** machine; again, the application needs the *client library*, but the database engine is typically a separate product / install that needs to happen for each client
- embedded databases - *this* is probably what you are aiming for; in this scenario, the "client library" actually includes the entire database engine, allowing the application to be entirely self-contained; this tends to offer the least features of the three, but usually enough for most common scenarios

So: as long as you limit yourself to the third category, you should be fine.

Comment: In case number 3, how does one embed the database engine into the application?  Would I use something like SQLite, or do the C# libraries include classes that act like a database server?

Comment: SQLite does the trick. EDIT: There are nuget packages that let you use Entity Framework with SQLite which makes the C# code used to interact with the DB much easier.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org), you don't need the client to have any DBMS installed.
It's [performance is really good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-sqlite), and you just need to get the [nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/) to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for an embedded database. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684595/embedded-database-for-net). SQL Server Compact from that list might be just what you are looking for.